# Trouble implementing custom loss function in Keras

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement a custom loss function in Keras. The model takes a lot of time to compile and runs out of memory (RAM).

My prediction has shape: (None, 16, 16, 5), where the last dimension has elements:

```
[probability, x_coordinate_of_box, y_coordinate of box, width_of_box, height_of_box]
```

I am trying to implement a function similar to this loss function:

[image]

```
import keras.backend as K
def yoloLoss(y_true, y_pred):
  sse = 0
  l_bbox = 0
  shape = y_pred.get_shape().as_list()
  w_coord = 1
  w_box = 5
  for x in range(32):
    for i in range(shape[1]):
      for j in range(shape[2]):
          sse += (y_pred[x][i][j][0] - y_true[x][i][j][0])**2
          l_bbox +=  w_coord*((y_pred[x][i][j][1] - y_true[x][i][j][1])**2 + (y_pred[x][i][j][2] - y_true[x][i][j][2])**2) + w_box*((y_pred[x][i][j][2]**0.5 - y_true[x][i][j][2]**0.5)**2 + (y_pred[x][i][j][3]**0.5 - y_true[x][i][j][3]**0.5)**2)
  return sse + l_bbox
```

Note: x is in range 32 as the batch_size is 32.

`K.get_shape().as_list()` or `K.int_shape()` returns the batch size as None

I expected the model to use the custom loss, but the `model.compile()` step keeps processing and runs out of memory/RAM.

Also, if someone could help me with getting the shape of the predictions on runtime, that would be really great!